# How to instal vim using salt stack?

Tags: saltstack, vim

I have salt-stack maser and minion servers which running on centos7. I want to install vim package in minion server. For that I have created srv directory and vim.sls file under etc.

My vim.sls file looks like this.

```
vim:
  pkg:
    - installed
```

When I run using  `salt '*' state.sls vim` getting an error.

```
192.168.94.155:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    No matching sls found for 'vim' in env 'base'
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the srv directory should be:

```
/srv/
 - salt
 - pillar
```

Your vim.sls should be in the salt directory and not in the /srv directory.

In addition, and beware that for vim, depending on the OS familly (Redhat and others) the package name is not always the same. and for this, using pillars could be very helpful:

```
{% if grains['os_family'] == 'RedHat' %}
apache: httpd
git: git
gvim: vim-X11
vim: vim-enhanced
{% elif grains['os_family'] == 'Debian' %}
apache: apache2
{% else %}
apache: apache2
git: git
gvim: gvim
vim: vim
{% endif %}
```

By doing so, you cann do the following thing

```
deploy editors:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - {{ pillar['vim'] }}
      - {{ pillar['gvim'] }}
```

And no matter on which OS family your minion is located, the correct package will be deployed.

Edit:
Here is the way I'm using my pillars:
in /srv/pillars I've got a top.sls file with this in it

```
base:
  '*':
    - packages
```

Then at the same level as the top.sls I've got a packages.sls file with the content I've posted before in it. That its possible to use {{ pillar['vim'] }} in my salt recipes for instance. But in your case it's not needed. It's just an easy way to handle various Linux flavor (RHEL, Debian & co) 
And If I want to add more variable data I can still add another sls at the same level

Comment: I don't have an idea about pillars. I have created directry called pillars in /srv location. Can you tell me how to add these scripts?

Comment: I've added to my answer the way I'm using the pillars. If you need more info let me know

Comment: Is it working for you? any issue?

Comment: Hey I got an error     `Data failed to compile:
----------
    Too many functions declared in state '192' in SLS 'top'`.

Comment: Can you post the sls file you are using? To see if we can pinpoint the reason for this error?